# Hosting Mutitenant Application on Windows Azure Management Portal

Tags: windows, azure, azure-deployment

I have gone through the Lab AdvancedWebAndWorkerRoles which you have provided in the latest training kit WAPTK. I followed the steps in  Exercise 1:registering sites,Applications and Virtual directories .It is running fine in windows azure emulator(locally),but i cannot find any steps to host in the windows azure management portal.

Can any one suggest(steps) how to host the same application in the windows azure management portal?

---

We know  how to deploy applications in windows azure portal.As i had mentioned in my  question about the Exercise 1:registering sites,Applications and Virtual directories in the training kit WAPTK ,we want to create the similar application and host in the azure.The steps to host the Exercise 1 application in management portal is not mentioned in the training kit.We tried to host the application in windows azure portal but it is not working as the ServiceDefinition.csdef include some different configurations.We wanted to know the steps to host that application in management portal.

Answer (score 0):

Under the **Introduction to Windows Azure** lab, look at *Exercise 3: Publishing a Windows Azure Application*. This shows how to publish via the portal. The basic steps:

- Build your Windows Azure service in Visual Studio, but tell it not to publish. Just generate the package file and configuration file.
- Create a new hosted service. This gets a name like `myapp.cloudapp.net`. You'll need to find a unique DNS prefix.
- Select the generated package file and configuration file, from the portal, which results in your service being launched. This takes a few minutes, and you can watch its status via the portal.

You may also publish directly from Visual Studio. See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460772.aspx) for instructions on setting up Visual Studio correctly (which basically imports your publishing settings from the portal). Visual Studio can perform all of the steps without having you to actually do anything in the portal (aside from exporting your publish settings).